# Sencha TOUCH ListPaging send Param from an existing store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Hello, I have a list with paging I want to send a param on load, this param is from another store.

```
Ext.define('WE3Chamados.store.Chamados', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'WE3Chamados.model.Chamado',
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://XXX/chamados.php',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty : 'chamados',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Like this

```
login_store = Ext.getStore('Login');
param_to_send_default = login_store.getAt(0).data.cod_usuario;
```

and send it as a default param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `extraParams` config for the `proxy` object:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    ...
    extraParams: {
        param_to_send_default: Ext.getStore('Login').getAt(0).get('cod_usuario)
    }
}
```